# Why return doesn't exit function in Java?

Tags: java, function, conditional-statements

I'm having problem with this function in Java. I don't understand why when `lastNodeAttributes==null` is true execution jumps to `return null;` as should, but right after that, instead of returning from function it jumps directly to `return fight...;` at the very end. Why first return doesn't exit but execution jumps to return in second conditional part?? How is this even possible? Please explain cause obviously I don't understand how basics of java work.

```
public Node undo() {
    Node lastNode=fight.getLastChild();
    NamedNodeMap lastNodeAttributes = lastNode.getAttributes();
    if(lastNodeAttributes == null) { return null; }
    else { 
        String lastNodeFighter = lastNodeAttributes.getNamedItem("fighter")
                                 .getNodeValue();
        String lastNodePoints = lastNodeAttributes.getNamedItem("points")
                                .getNodeValue();
        if(Integer.parseInt(lastNodeFighter) == 1) {
            fighter1score-=Integer.parseInt(lastNodePoints);    
        }
        else { fighter2score -= Integer.parseInt(lastNodePoints); }
        return fight.removeChild(fight.getLastChild());
    }
}
```

Comment: question title doesn't match question???

Comment: *"How is this even possible?"* => it's not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you make affirmations in your questions which are false. Please verify with a debugger.

Comment: Apologies for the title, fixed now

Comment: *Why return doesn't exit function in Java?* -> it does. Your code must be wrong.

Comment: How do you know what the function returning?

Comment: @dystroy ..I'm using Eclipse debugger obviously for some reason what it shows is not accurate as it still shows that the second return line is executed.

Comment: Also if downvoters could explain please why the question was downvoted. The title was wrong, that's my honest mistake and I fixed it as soon as realized, it took 5 minutes most. Other than that is there anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is impossible. A return statement does indeed always return what is stated. There are a few possibilities to why you might see this behaviour *in the debugger*

- You're not debugging the code you think you're debugging. The debugger might be loading a different class than you think. Try to clean and recompile your code and debug it again.
- The code is compiled in release mode, and has switched your statements around. Debugging in release mode with optimized code can sometimes throw the debugger off so that the wrong statement shows as executed in your debugger than what is actually executed. Are you sure that the code you're debugging is unoptimized.
- Threading issues can also cause strange jumps if you don't think carefully. If you have breakpoints on both return statements and multiple threads running then one thread might hit the first return, and then another thread might hit the second return. It's not wrong, it's just how debugging multithreaded applications work.

Checking the actual return value will also confirm that indeed only one `return` statement has executed. Do this by placing the breakpoint at the caller instead of the callee

Comment: Well, I checked return value and indeed it returns null as expected, debugger in Eclipse still shows as execution jumps to the second return. Very confusing and I have been debugging this for a while but still don't know why debugger behaves like it does. Anyhow, return value is correct though so thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Start debugging your application first. A good debugging tutorial can be found here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Verify, that lastNodeAttributes is really null. Also check, if maybe the method is executed twice, where in the first case lastNodeAttributes is null and in the second case it is not.

Answer (score -1):

Return does exit the method. check that you're using the latest compiled class.
Try to do a clean build.
Start debugging from the first line making sure that you're not running the same method twice.
In case of doubt, add a system.out in the beginning of your class to make sure you're checking the right class version

Comment: At least say why you downvote. I see not reason for it